# How do I upload a video from my iPhone to Dropbox?

Tags: video

I have a video and want to upload it to Dropbox to send it to someone.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

> **Upload photos and videos manually**
>
> 1. Open the Dropbox app.
> 2. Tap the + (plus) icon.
> 3. Tap **Upload photos**.
> 4. Find the files you want to upload, and tap to select them for upload.
>
>    - A check mark indicates the file has been selected
> 5. Tap **Next** to enter the **Save Settings** screen. 
>      Choose which folder your
>      photos will upload to, or rename all photos at once:
>
>    - To rename all photos at once, tap **Rename All** and enter the new name
>        for your photos. Photos are then automatically numbered in the order
>        in which they were added. You can tap and hold the three horizontal
>        lines to the right of an image to reorder it.
>    - Tap Confirm to return    to the Save Settings screen
> 6. Tap Upload.

https://help.dropbox.com/syncing-uploads/upload-mobile